# Custom date format problem in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, metadata, data-annotations

I have the following model and view, and I would very much like to accept date values in the format 'dd/MM/yyyy'.  However, despite using the `DisplayFormat` annotation, I still get a validation error using my chosen format.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MilestoneMetadata))]
public partial class Milestone {    
    public class MilestoneMetadata {
        [Required][DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public object Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date) %> 
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date) %>
</div>
```

Namespaces etc. are correct for the annotations and main classes to be in the same namespace.  This is not my first encounter with this issue, but I see no results from annotations that are supposed to affect mappings between form values and the model.  A template for dates doesn't help me because I can't find a way to set how dates are parsed when posting a create or update.

**NOTE:**  *I do not wish to use a different UI culture to achieve this.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the [`uiCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) in web.config (If you leave it to `auto` the client browser culture will be used):

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" 
               requestEncoding="utf-8" 
               responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

This will force `en-US` culture format when the default model binder parses request values (adapt as necessary to the needed culture).

Also having a `Date` property typed to `System.Object` is not a very good design.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I've found if I set culture to 'en-GB', I get the correct format handling.  If I set it to 'en-ZA', I have to use the format 'yyyy/MM/dd'. My real goal is to not change the culture, but still change the date format.

The property that is of type System.Object is never used.  The real date property is declared as System.DateTime.  The 'object' property is only used for it's attributes.

Comment: In this case you would need to write a custom model binder and manually parse the request string into a DateTime.

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  I have already done a model binder for all DateTime values, but this seems like an extraordinary length to go to for a task like this.